# Not able to access property of an object

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services

I'm using `$resource` for making restful request to the server. 
My code is

service.js

```
.factory('userServ',function($resource){
   return $resource('url/:id',{id:'@id'},{
          me: 'GET',isArray:false,url:'url2'}
});
})
```

I'm using this service in the controller like this

```
$scope.userDetails = userService.me();
console.log($scope.userDetails) // gives all the details of the user
console.log($scope.userDetails.username) // gives undefined. But username is there in the object
```

So how can I access that from the object

Comment: you need to put `.then` callback over you service method call..and inside that callback have success and error callback

Comment: @PankajParkar Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your aprroach, promise is not resolved. So you are not able to naccess data.
Here,

```
  $scope.userDetails = userService.me();
```

Promise is not resolved. when you expand your Object you will see `resolved:false`. Although you will be able to see data inside `$scope.userDetails` you needed.

So, first you need to wait till promise is resolved.For this you can use `.then` method.

```
var CallApi = userService.me().$promise;  //Promise yet to be Resolved
       CallApi.then(function (res)){           //Promise resolved here
        $scope.userDetails = res;
        console.log($scope.userDetails)
        console.log($scope.userDetails.username)
      }
     })
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: @abarisone I will follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Your resource object returns a promise. Read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

```
var myResource = $resource('url/:id',{id:'@id'},{
      me: 'GET',isArray:false,url:'url2'}
});
```

In order to get the data out of it you need to call the methods of the promise itself. They are GET, PUT and SAVE.

But here you only have a GET mentioned there.

So if you resolve your promise by calling

```
var myResult = [];
myResource.then(function(data){
    myresult = date;
});
```

Now, 'myResult' here will have your returned data.

It can also be called like this ():

```
.get({userId:123})
.$promise.then(function(user) {
  $scope.user = user;
});
```

Again I would recommend reading the angular docs to get a better understanding.